# Jump *to* end of paragraph?

Tags: cursor-movement, visual-block

I often find I want to quickly select all the characters in an aligned column, something like this:

```
this.p           = obj.['propery'];
this.prop        = obj.['proper'];
this.proper      = obj.['prop'];
this.property    = obj.['p'];
```

Say I want to select the `.`s with visual block selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).
If it's not immediately obvious how many rows there are (perhaps there are more), I typically use <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>}</kbd> once in visual block select mode to jump the appropriate distance. However, they go one line too far; if the following line is blank the cursor move to the first column, selecting far more than I want.

Is there an equivalent to <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>}</kbd> which jumps *to* the last line in the paragraph, while maintaining the current column?

---

My question is similar to [How do I move by paragraphs, but end up *in* the paragraph?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14847/6079) but the answer given there (mapping `j` or `k` after a `{` or `}`) won't work for me; the column will be lost.

Comment: I often have the same problem. I have found that setting [`'relativenumber'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27relativenumber%27) can be a great help in getting it right the first time around.

Comment: @filbranden Do you find it gets in the way of using absolute line numbers to say, jump to lines mentioned in error messages?

Comment: Not really, since in that case I'll use a command (e.g. `346G`) or the quickfix window. You can also use both `'relativenumber'` *and* `'number'` together, in which case it will show the absolute line for the current line, and relative around it. But yeah, I'd be curious to see if anyone has a better suggestion on how to handle this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vnoremap <silent>x :<C-U>call cursor(line("'}")-1,col("'>"))<CR>`<1v``
```

Explanation:

- `vnoremap <silent>x` --- remap something useless in visual mode (`x` is the same as `d`)
- `:<C-U>` --- drop visual line range (also switches to normal mode)
- `call cursor(...)<CR>` --- set cursor position

  - `line("'}")-1` --- the last line of the current paragraph (except if it's the last paragraph in the whole file, but it's not that important, I think; use `line("'}") - empty(getline(line("'}")))` if it is)
  - `col("'>")` --- the end column of the visual selection
- `<1v --- restore visual mode
- `` --- jump back to the latest jump, i.e. extend selection till that `cursor()` position

Comment: You can handle the last paragraph if you replace `line("'}")-1` with `line("'}") - (line("'}") == line("$") ? 0 : 1)`.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer In fact, I wanted first to do `line("'}") - (line("'}") != line("$"))` (which is basically the same thing). But the problem is that the last line can be empty too.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer So a "bullet-proof" version should be: `line("'}") - empty(getline(line("'}")))`

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I don't understand you first comment. If the last line is empty, the last line of the last paragraph is not the last line of the buffer and subtracting 1 will work.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer If it's empty then line("'}") == line("$"), therefore your expression yields the number of the last (empty) line.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tested with the wrong examples. :-(

Comment: The leader key (h mapleader) is a good candidate for maps

Comment: @D.BenKnoble For normal mode, certainly, yes. But for visual mode one can probably find more "free stuff".

Answer (score 1):

I have the same frustration, and I've come up with:

```
vnoremap <expr> } mode()=~'\cv' ? '}' : line("'}")-line('.')-1..'j'
```

This remaps the } key so that it behaves normally *except* when in visual-block mode. In visual-block mode it jumps to the line before the next blank line (and stays in the same column).

It is an expr map, so it evaluates to a string every time it is invoked. This string becomes the mapping.

In non-block visual modes, it evaluates to `}`, so no change.

In block-visual mode it evaluates to `#j` where # is `line("'}")-line('.')-1`

- `line("'}")` line number for end of paragraph
- `line('.')` line number for current line
- `-1` one line before

You can change the `-1` to `empty(getline(line("'}")))` (as per Matt's answer) to get this to work with paragraphs at the end of a file. Like this:

```
vnoremap <expr> } mode()=~'\cv' ? '}' : line("'}")-line('.')-empty(getline(line("'}")))..'j'
```